# Query data from PostgreSQL from two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL **COUNTRIES** and **CITIES**. I use node-postgres for nodejs.

**COUNTRIES**

```
id name
1  USA
2  GERMANY
3  CHINA
```

**CITIES**

```
id    name          country_id
1     New York      1
2     Chicago       1
3     Hong Kong     3
4     Boston        1
5     Beijing       3
6     Berlin        2
```

If it possible. Can I get data like?

```
[{
  id: 1,
  country: 'USA',
  cities: [{
     id: 1,
     city: 'New York',
  },{
     id: 2,
     city: 'Chicago',
  },{
     id: 4,
     city: 'Boston',
  }] 
}, {
  id: 2,
  country: 'GERMANY',
  cities: [{
     id: 6,
     city: 'Berlin',
  }],
...
}]
```

Comment: You strictly need JSON output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can aggregate as:

```
select c.id, c.name, array_agg( (ci.id, ci.name) ) as cities
from countries c join
     cities ci
     on ci.country_id = c.id
group by c.id;
```

This returns the result using Postgres types.

As Json, this would look like:

```
select c.id, c.name,
       json_agg(json_build_object('id', ci.id, 'name', ci.name))  as cities
from countries c join
     cities ci
     on ci.country_id = c.id
group by c.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a inner join
Something like this will work

```
SELECT
   countries.id,
   countries.name,
   cities.id,
   cities.name
FROM
   countries
INNER JOIN countries ON cities counties.id = cities.country_id;
```

For more info, you can visit [postgreql](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/) documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (performed on MySQL Workbench):

```sql
select a.id as ID, a.name as CityName,b.name as  CountryName from cities as a
INNER join couNtries as b on a.COUNTRY_id=b.id GROUP BY 2;
```

Comment: Please Try the Above Query and I have used Mysql Workbench